# onLongClick for TextView fires link inside textview

Tags: android

In my app I have textViews with links inside. I need to separate normal click which will open web link and longClick which will open context menu. But whenever I make longClick, when I release my finger it fires web link, which opens browser.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
textView.setText(some text with web links);
textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Log.d("RAFL", "longclick works");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this helps.

```
    textview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            isLongClick= true;
            return true;
        }
    });
    textview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && isLongClick){
                isLongClick= false;
                return true;
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                isLongClick= false;
            }
            return v.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

    });
```

Comment: nice question, nice answer!

Comment: After 3 months I finally fixed an issue I had thanks to you, my greatest thank you.